# Bxslider get blank on next slide in Firefox mac

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I have problem with bxslider on (Firefox mac) and get blank video on next slide.

not sure what's the problem, looks good when I check on other browsers

this my test link - http://elixirbox.com/temp/bxslider/

and this is my js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    video: true
});


$('iframe').each(function()
     {var url = $(this).attr("src");
      var result = url.search(/youtube/i);
      if(result!=-1)
       {result = url.indexOf('?');
        if(result!=-1)  
          {$(this).attr("src",url+"&wmode=transparent");
          } else {$(this).attr("src",url+"?wmode=transparent");}
       }
     });
      });
```

this is my html code

```
<div  style="width:500px; margin:0 auto">
<ul class="bxslider">
<li>
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/51686357" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</li>
<li>
    <iframe title="YouTube video player" width="307" height="190" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/yX93uJshpj0" frameborder="0" wmode="Opaque" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</li>
<li>
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/51686357" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you've found a solution for this yet, but I've seen two suggested.

1. add useCSS: false to your function call.
2. add ?wmode=opaque (or &wmode=opaque, if you've already used ?) at the end of your YouTube call.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Firefox (Chrome & IE are fine) when embedding swf files into bxslider. Adding wmode="opaque" to the <object> tag and changing the bxslider config "video" to false will make it works perfectly. My code:

```
<li>
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="210240.swf" width="260px" height="110px" id="p_2730_w_318" wmode="opaque"></object>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    //video: true   
  });
});
</script>
```